# R table conversion

Tags: r

Hello I am working with a table with these characteristics:

```
2000    0.051568
2000    0.04805
2002    0.029792
2002    0.056141
2008    0.047285
2008    0.038989
```

And I need to convert it to something like this:

```
2000       2002      2008

0.051568   0.029792  0.047285
0.04805    0.056141  0.038989
```

I would be grateful if somebody could give me a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a relatively simple solution:

```
# CREATE ORIGINAL DATA.FRAME
df <- read.table(text="2000    0.051568
2000    0.04805
2002    0.029792
2002    0.056141
2008    0.047285 
2008    0.038989", header=FALSE)
names(df) <- c("year", "value")

# MODIFY ITS LAYOUT
df2 <- as.data.frame(split(df$value, df$year))
df2
#      X2000    X2002    X2008
# 1 0.051568 0.029792 0.047285
# 2 0.048050 0.056141 0.038989
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are new to R, so I'm going to guess what you mean and give you some more correct terminology.  If I guess wrong, then at least this may help you to clarify the question.

In R, a table is a special case of a matrix that arises from cross-tabulation.  What I think you have (or want) to start with is a `data.frame`.  A `data.frame` is a set of columns with potentially different types, but all the same length; it is "rectangular" in that sense.  Generally, elements in the same positions in the columns (that is, each row) of a `data.frame` are related to each other.  The columns of a `data.frame` have names, as can the rows.

```
long <- data.frame(year=c(2000,2000,2002,2002,2008,2008),
                   val=c(0.051568, 0.04805, 0.029792, 
                         0.056141, 0.047285, 0.038989))
```

Which when printed looks like

```
> long
  year      val
1 2000 0.051568
2 2000 0.048050
3 2002 0.029792
4 2002 0.056141
5 2008 0.047285
6 2008 0.038989
```

By itself, this isn't enough, because for your desired output, you need to specify which value for, say, 2000 is in the first row and which is in the second (etc., if there were more).  In your example, it is just the order they are in.

```
long$targetrow = 1:2
```

Which makes `long` now look like

```
> long
  year      val targetrow
1 2000 0.051568         1
2 2000 0.048050         2
3 2002 0.029792         1
4 2002 0.056141         2
5 2008 0.047285         1
6 2008 0.038989         2
```

Now you can use `reshape` on it.

```
reshape(long, idvar="targetrow", timevar="year",  direction="wide")
```

which gives

```
> reshape(long, idvar="targetrow", timevar="year",  direction="wide")
  targetrow val.2000 val.2002 val.2008
1         1 0.051568 0.029792 0.047285
2         2 0.048050 0.056141 0.038989
```

More complicated transformations are possible using the `reshape2` package, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

probably i am understanding this wrong but is `?reshape` what you are looking for?
from the examples:

```
summary(Indometh) 
wide <- reshape(Indometh, v.names="conc", idvar="Subject", timevar="time", direction="wide")

wide
```